# XML + XSL to XSLT for an HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, null, transformation

Sorry if my Post won´t be so good i am not that good in expressing myself.

What i want:

I´ve got an XML and a XSL Data i want to convert to an XSLT for an HTML. 
As transformating i use Altova XMLSpy and this webpage: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

What i´ve got:

***My XML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Style.xsl"?>
<Configuration>
 <Environment>
  ...
 </Environment>
  <Configurations>
  ...
  <Config>
  ...  
  </Config>
 </Configurations>
</Configuration>
```

**My XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="4">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Configuration"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>&gt;
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Environment">
        <tr>Environment</tr>
        <br/>
        <td> <th>Text</th>
    <xsl:value-of select="Environment"/>
        </td>
       <td> <th>Text2</th>
    <xsl:value-of select="config"/>
        </td>
           ...
           ... 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is just a example how i build it.

so far everything was fine, but then:

***Problem:***

If i start my XML in Firefox now everything works. If i start it in IE or Chrome i just get the XML Data but not the Table.
Trying to transform it in XSLT gives me this Error: 
Unable to perform XSL transformation on your XML file. null

I hope you can help me. I am a bloody beginner in XML/XSl/XSLT but i hope my post will give you the Information you need.

Greetings

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a very common beginner's mistake:

```
<xsl:template match="Environment">
   <tr>Environment</tr>...
   <xsl:value-of select="Environment"/>
```

In this template, the context node is an Environment element, and your xsl:value-of instruction is looking for a child of that element with the name Environment. But your Environment element (I assume) does not have any Environment children. What you should write (I assume) is

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

However, I don't think this is the whole problem. It doesn't account for all the symptoms described. You've actually made another beginner's mistake, which is trying to run your XSLT code in the browser before testing it elsewhere. The browser-based XSLT engines give lousy diagnostics (even when you use something like Firebug). Get your code working first in a desktop environment - preferably an XML IDE like oXygen. You'll then get a decent explanation of what is wrong.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your respond. I get the points you told me so far. The only thing wich is confusing me is the browser Problem. I Programmed my Code in Stylus Studio and there it worked super fine as well. Even in the preview. Well i write it again in altova now and keep you updated if the Problem still exists

Comment: OK, thanks, that's new information. If it works in Stylus Studio but not in the browser that greatly narrows down what might be wrong. But I can't see exactly what the problem is from the information given.

Comment: Hey, you are the best human in the world :-) I fixed it it, i don´t really know how but it works fine now. I just started a new Project and copy pasted my stuff in it and it started to work! I am super thankful for your help! go on Stackoverflow community you saved me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here Is The Modified Version of Your Code.

XSL Template Match Must match the XML node you wish to apply templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="Configuration">
      <html>
        <body>
          <table border="4">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Environment"/>
          </table>
          <table border="4">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Configurations"/>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Environment">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Configurations">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Config"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Config">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```